# Apache redirect - remove all queries

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, url

I am trying to remove all queries in URL:

- `https://api.myserver.com/image.png?arg=0` should become
- `https://api.myserver.com/image.png`

I used this:

```
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^arg=0$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

And this is the result:

`https://api.myserver.com/home/usrn32/domains/myserver.com/public_html/image.png`

So the params are removed, but the path is absolute instead of relative. Also, I want to catch all `arg` numbers, not just `0`.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is in a *directory* context. In which case the `$1` backreference does not contain a slash prefix (because the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not contain a slash prefix), so it is seen as a *relative* path substitution. mod_rewrite adds back the directory-prefix (ie. `/home/usrn32/domains/myserver.com/public_html/`) to the *substitution* when it is *relative*.

You need to explicitly include the slash prefix on the *susbtitution* (or use a `RewriteBase` directive), so that it is no longer *relative*. For example:

```
RewriteRule      (.*)               /$1?     [R=permanent,L]
```

Also, you probably want to include the `L` flag, to prevent further rewrites (if you have any).

> Also, I want to catch all arg numbers, not just 0.

Modify your *CondPattern* (`^arg=0$`) to something like `^arg=\d+$` (1 or more digits).

In Summary:

```
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^arg=\d+$
RewriteRule      (.*)               /$1?     [R=permanent,L]
```

> remove all queries

If you literally wanted to remove *all* query string parameters, then you could change the *CondPattern* to just a single dot (ie. `.`) to match any character.